# What is the adjoint of $x + \frac{d}{dx}?$

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, adjoint-operators

I have solved other problems like this using integration by parts. In this case, I can't figure out what to make each part for the integration. The question is true/false.  Ultimately to show this you have to find the adjoint and see if it is what they claim it is, i.e.,  $\displaystyle uv - \int vdu$.

What do you make $u$ and $v$?

> If $\langle f \vert g \rangle = \displaystyle \int_0^{\infty} f(x) g(x) e^{-x} dx$ for functions $f,g \in L_2([0,\infty))$ and $L = \left(x + \dfrac{d}{dx} \right)$ (assume that all elements of $L_2([0,\infty))$ are differentiable), its adjoint is $L^* = \left(x - \dfrac{d}{dx} \right)$.

Comment: A [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/182598/finding-the-adjoint-of-an-operator).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We want $L^*$ such that
$$\langle f \vert Lg \rangle = \langle L^*f \vert g \rangle$$
We have
$$S=\int_0^{\infty} e^{-x}f(x)\left(x+\dfrac{d}{dx}\right)g(x) dx = \int_0^{\infty}x e^{-x}f(x) g(x) dx + \int_0^{\infty} e^{-x} f(x) dg(x)$$
We have
$$\int_0^{\infty} e^{-x} f(x) dg(x) = \int_0^{\infty} d\left(e^{-x} f(x)g(x)\right) - \int_0^{\infty} g(x) d\left(e^{-x} f(x)\right)$$
Hence,
$$\int_0^{\infty} g(x) d\left(e^{-x} f(x)\right) = \int_0^{\infty} g(x)\left(e^{-x} \dfrac{df}{dx} - e^{-x} f(x)\right) dx$$
Hence,
$$S = \int_0^{\infty}e^{-x}\overbrace{\left(xf(x)-\dfrac{df}{dx}+f(x)\right)}^{L^*f}g(x)dx + \int_0^{\infty} d\left(e^{-x} f(x)g(x)\right)$$
Hence, the adjoint is
$$L^* = \left(x+1 - \dfrac{d}{dx}\right)$$

Comment: I'm not seeing how the last term reduces to zero.

Comment: @JohnMoeller The last term integrates to $\left. e^{-x} f(x) g(x) \right\vert_0^{\infty}$. For $L^2$ functions, with $f(0) = g(0) = 0$, the term goes off. Hence, $L^*$ is the adjoint of the operator on the subspace of function $S^* = \{f(x) \in L^2([0,\infty)): f(x) = 0\}$.

Comment: But what if $f(x) = e^{-x}$? Then $f$ is square-integrable on $[0,\infty]$. I don't see why $f(0)$ has to be $0$.

Comment: @JohnMoeller The adjoint is usually only defined on a subspace of the original space.

Comment: But the OP's question doesn't have the constraint that $f(0) = g(0) = 0$.

Comment: @JohnMoeller What I meant is that the adjoint need not always exist on the entire space. If it exists on a sufficiently large subspace, which in this case is the subspace $S^* \subset L^2$, we typically call $L^*$ as the adjoint without specifying the subspace $S^*$.

Comment: @JohnMoeller I googled about this and found a relevant pdf  with some nice examples. You might also be interested in this.(http://www.math.vt.edu/people/russell/m2k_fsp_diffop.pdf). The author also seems to agree that the adjoint need not always exist on the entire space.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. I'm still struggling to figure out how to drop that extra "1" in the adjoint.

Comment: @JohnMoeller Since the question is a true or false question, I would assume the answer is false. :) $L^*$ would have been $\left(x- \dfrac{d}{dx}\right)$ if the inner product was just $\displaystyle \int_0^{\infty} f(x) g(x) dx$. Probably the motivation of the question was to highlight the fact that the adjoint depends on the inner product.

Comment: Ah, good point. My brain put "show that" in the consequent and I didn't notice the specification in the OP's question.

Comment: how did you derive the this term  xf(x) in the third line.  I get 1− ddx but i cannot derive the x

Comment: @olliepower Which $xf(x)$? Note that $\left(x+ \dfrac{d}{dx}\right)g(x) = x g(x) + \dfrac{d g(x)}{dx}$.