# compute adjoint operator

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory

Let $M: P_{1}\rightarrow P_{1}$ be defined by $M(f)=f^{'}+f$, i.e. $M(a_{0}+a_{1}x)=a_{1}+a_{0}+a_{1}x$. Find the adjoint $M^{*}$ of $M$, i.e find $M^{*}(a_{0}+a_{1}x_{1})$, assuming that $L^{2}(0,1)$ inner product is imposed on $P_{1}$. $\langle f(x),g(x)\rangle =\int^{1}_{0}f(x)g(x)dx$.

Comment: This looks like a homework question; please see [how to ask](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question) such questions.  In any case, people here don't tend to like textbook-style problems with no work shown and phrased as commands.

Answer (score 2):

Let's find an *orthogonal* basis for the given inner product. 
Luckily, $\|1\|=\sqrt{\langle 1,1\rangle}=\sqrt{\int_0^11}=1$. But $x$ is not orthogonal to $1$, so we have to modify it:
$$\langle x,1\rangle =\int_0^11\cdot x\,dx=\frac12\,,$$
so that $(x-\frac12)\perp 1$. So is its double, $p:=\,2x-1$. Its norm can be obtained:
$\|p\|^2=\|(2x-1)\|^2=\int_0^1(2x-1)^2\,dx=\frac43-2+1=\frac13$.

Then, use the general fact that a vector $v$ can be decomposed in the orthogonal basis $e_1,e_2,...$ as 
$$v=\frac{\langle v,e_1\rangle}{\|e_1\|^2} e_1+\frac{\langle v,e_2\rangle}{\|e_2\|^2} e_2+\dots$$

So that, now we can apply this to arrive at $M^*$:
$$M^*(1)= \langle M^*(1),\,1\rangle\, +3\,\langle M^*(1),\,2x-1\rangle\cdot (2x-1)= \\
= \langle 1,M(1)\rangle+3\,\langle1,M(2x-1)\rangle\cdot(2x-1)\,.$$
Similarly one can obtain $M^*(x)$.

Comment: can you make use of $<M(f),g>=<f,M^{*}(g)>$?

Comment: Didn't I use it?

Comment: One can also introduce an *orthonormal* basis, and work with matrices. Now we can fix $(1,\sqrt3\cdot(2x-1))$, now both these has norm $1$, and are orthogonal to each other (w.r.t. the $L^2$ inner product). Then, coordinating $M$ in this basis, we get $$[M]=\pmatrix{1&2\sqrt3\\0&1}\,$$
so its adjoint (*in the same basis!*) is $$[M^*]=\pmatrix{1&0\\2\sqrt3&1}\,.$$ Looks odd, but it gives the same as my solution.

Comment: My approach: $<M(f),g>=<f,M^{*}(g)>$, $f=a_{0}+a_{1}x$,$g=b_{0}+b_{1}x$, $<M(f),g>=\int^{1}_{0}(a_{1}+a_{0}+a_{1}x)(b_0+b_{1}x)dx$, but I don't how to continue. Can you prove it following my idea?

Comment: For start, you have to calculate $\int_0^1x^2$ and $\int_0^1x$ and $\int_0^11$ anyway. Please read through my answer. If something is not clear about it, ask more specifically.

Comment: I have read your answer carefully, according your answer,$M^{*}(x)=7x-3$,am I right?

Comment: I think, for calculating adjoint one needs to work in orthonormal or at least orthogonal basis (or, either one can write up the Gram matrix of the inner product in the standard basis). Using orthonormal basis $e_1,e_2,..,e_n$ you probably know that a vector's $i$th coordinate can be obtained by $\langle v,e_i\rangle$. I have used the modification of this statement to orthogonal bases.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/182598/finding-the-adjoint-of-an-operator

Comment: Yes, I got $M^*(1)=12x-5$ and $M^*(x)=7x-3$. From that you can write up it for general $M^*(a+bx)$.\

Comment: Is $M^{*}$ linear operator?

Comment: And I am thinking if the number of basis is too large, how can you calculate the basis?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9179/discussion-between-berci-and-user81235)

Comment: Yes, $M^*$ is linear.
The basis has $2$ elements, as $P_1$ has dimension two. Its standard basis consists of $1$ and $x$. The orthogonal basis that I used consists of $1$ and $(2x-1)$.